# Should i save single use site options in seperate tables ? - Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

On my website (CMS system) i have some available options

For example:

- Analytics code (always just a single code)
- Maintenance mode (always 1 or 0)
- ...

Should i split these options into separate tables? So in this case that means a Table for Analytics and a Table for Maintenance Mode . This is more convenient for development. But is this really a good practice?

Or should i make 1 options table? But how would this work in actual development? I could seed a single row in the options table with default values and when a user changes or adds an option i always just update that single row.  This second option also seems like bending the rules.

I use MySQL and Laravel 5.2 on this website. If that's relevant.

**Edit**
Using a custom config file is not really an option because a user needs to add/update these values

Comment: In this case is more tables totaly unnecessarily. Just create one table (e.g. settings) with columns name and value (name off setting - analytics, value - analytics code). If you will have more maitenance modes (e.g. one for frontend and one for backend), you just give proper names for them.

Comment: Do you _have to_ store your options in a database? Would it be an option to store your options in a custom config file like this? http://tutsnare.com/how-to-create-custom-configuration-in-laravel/

Comment: @Adrenaxus Storing this options in database is imho good solution. You can create simple backend settings page in your application a then changing them there without acces to files.

Comment: @Adrenaxus that seems like a nice way to do it. But a user needs to add/update values of those items. Is that possible with a config file? Don't see anything on that in the given lnk

Comment: @Christophvh If the user needs to update those values, it is indeed better, if not mandatory, that they are stored in a database. In that case, the simplest solution IMHO would be to add those options to your `user` table.

Comment: @Adrenaxus adding it to my user table is not the solution because that would mean that a every user has a different analytics code? These options are related to the global website not the user

Comment: @Christophvh But you said that a user needs to add/update those settings?

Comment: @Adrenaxus Every user that has the role of Admin will be able to change these values in a control panel. Those are website settings not user settings

Comment: You can store them in database for those settings that you know that exist for sure create a column and add a column of type JSON for Settings that the admin adds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems that there is not a single correct way/convention to do this. I am going with 1 options table , which i am going to seed the first time my application gets installed. The user has an options panel where they can update the values. They cant create or delete them.